# Cleaning up DistributionGroup in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, compare, exchange-server

I'm fairly new to PowerShell and I'm trying to accomplish the following:

I have a PS command to get users from AD using `Get-ADUser` & it's filtered on Department.

Then I use `Get-DistributionGroupMember` to get another batch of users from a specific DistributionGroup.

The `Get-ADuser` output is:

- John
- Linda
- Dave
- Frank

The `Get-DistributionGroupMember` output is:

- John
- Linda
- Dave
- Robert
- Ryan

What I'm trying to do is see if all users obtained with `Get-ADUser` are identical to the DistributionGroup members.

If there are users in the `Get-ADUser` output who are not in the DistributionGroup, I want to add them to the group. So in this case **Frank** would have to be added to the DistributionGroup using **Add-DistributionGroupMember**.

The second thing I want to do is remove members from the DistributionGroup if they are in the group but not in the `Get-ADUser` output. So in this case **Robert & Ryan** would have to be removed from the DistributionGroup using `Remove-DistributionGroupMember`.

I was thinking about emptying the DistributionGroup & refill it with the data from the `Get-ADUser` command but there should be a better way to accomplish the above scenario without having to actually clear the DistributionGroup right? I don't want to risk people using the DistributionGroup just when my script cleared it.

This is what I used for clearing the group & just repopulate it:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Department | Where-Object {$_.Department -eq "ICT"} | Select-Object sAMAccountName
$group = "DG_ICT"

Get-DistributionGroupMember $group | Remove-DistributionGroupMember $group -Confirm:$False

foreach($u in $users) { Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $u.sAMAccountName }
```

I just don't know enough PowerShell atm to think of the correct way to do this without emptying the group, so any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thank you!

Comment: welcome to SO! Provide some code for your question: what you tried, etc See also  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added the code in my original post I initially used for clearing & repopulating but that's plain basic. I'm new at this. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would approach this is by leveraging the `Compare-Object`.

When adding and removing members from a distribution group, you do not need to go through exchange. You can control the membership through AD.

The following example should start you in the right direction:

```
#get users
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {Darpartment -like "*"}
#get group object
$group = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -eq ".TEST Group"} -Properties Members

#compare by DN
$compare = Compare-Object $users.distinguishedName $group.members

#users not in group
$notInGroup = ($compare | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}).InputObject 
#users in group
$notInGetAD = ($compare | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"}).InputObject

#Add to group -- only if true
if($notInGroup)
{
    $group | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $notInGroup -Confirm:$false
}
#remove from group -- only if true
if($notInGetAD)
{

    $group | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $notInGetAD -Confirm:$false
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jrider ! I tweaked your example to work in my environment but the last 2 statements to add & remove groupmembers only work if there's only 1 result in $notInGroup & $notInGetAD - for more than 1 result I get a convert error because $notInGroup/$notInGetAD is now an array instead of a single string. If there's more than 1 user to be removed I would have to loop both $notInGroup & $notInGetAD to have them all added/removed, correct?

Comment: This is what I came up with to loop through those arrays. I feel like this is the shortest way to do that, correct? `foreach ($toAdd in $notInGroup) { $groupName | Add-DistributionGroupMember -Member $toAdd -Confirm:$False }

foreach ($toRemove in $notInGetAD) {$groupName | Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Member $toRemove -Confirm:$False }`

Comment: you can do it with a `foreach` with your example it will work. `Remove-ADGroupMember` and `Add-ADGroupMember` `-Members` accepts an array, so there is no need to iterate through it. I updated the answer to check if the `compare-object` is `$true`